# How to Install netbeans 6.x in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans

I installed netbeans 7.X on ubuntu 13.04. But it either keep crashing or it doesn't load the project list.
I find on the internet that this is a bug.
in software centre of Ubuntu13.04 only netbeans 7.X is listed.

can someone please tell me how can I install a lower version of the same.

Comment: it may be more appropriate to post on [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans should not crash, or you can file a bug report. Please try a manual install from the Netbeans website, not from the software center.
That is the way to install an older version as well.

You can find the linux downloads here: https://netbeans.org/downloads/